# Can I switch between mapIcons using a if-statement?

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, map

I want to be able to switch between different map icon colors depending on the StageName.
For example I want the StageName **"Rev Rec'd"** to be blue, and **"Signed"** and **"Signed LOI"** to be green.

**My JS code:**

```
// Changes the map-marker icon color and shape.
            if(record.StageName == "Rev Rec'd" ){

                mapIcon : {

                    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                    fillColor: '#0079af',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWeight: 1,
                    scale: 1,

                }

            }else{

                mapIcon : {

                    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
                    fillColor: '#09A711',
                    fillOpacity: 1,
                    strokeWeight: 1,
                    scale: 1,
    
                }


            }
```

Would using a if/else statement be possible, or is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably want a ternary operator:

```
mapIcon: {
    path: 'M 0,0 C -2,-20 -10,-22 -10,-30 A 10,10 0 1,1 10,-30 C 10,-22 2,-20 0,0 z',
    fillColor: record.StageName == "Rev Rec'd"? '#0079af': '#09A711',
    fillOpacity: 1,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    scale: 1,
}
```

However, be careful. It looks you're using object notation:

```
{ property: value }
```

When you're actually trying to assign a value:

```
mapIcon = { ... }
```

There is an uncommonly used JavaScript feature known as a [`label`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label):

```
label: variable
```

In this case, `label` is essentially ignored, which means no assignment occurs to `label`.

Comment: Thank you! That worked for me